# UISearchBar in a UIViewController crashing

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar, unrecognized-selector, uivewcontroller

I am having a weird crash when using UISearchBar. I have a view controller on a storyboard and everything works fine but as soon as a drag a UISearchBar in the view controller and then run the app, I get the following crash:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x6d83b, 0x0462169e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x0462169e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x045ef2c5 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 101
    frame #2: 0x043609c9 libsystem_sim_c.dylib`abort + 127
    frame #4: 0x03a1c35d CoreFoundation`__handleUncaughtException + 749
    frame #5: 0x0370bb8b libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 100
    frame #6: 0x03ee5f60 libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 14
    frame #7: 0x03ee597d libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw + 116
    frame #8: 0x0370b9fc libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw + 323
    frame #9: 0x03a29243 CoreFoundation`-[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    frame #10: 0x0397c50b CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 1019
    frame #11: 0x0397c0ee CoreFoundation`__forwarding_prep_0___ + 14
    frame #12: 0x01fd0ba4 UIKit`-[UISearchBar(UISearchBarStatic) _updateMagnifyingGlassView] + 486
    frame #13: 0x01fd0cdb UIKit`-[UISearchBar(UISearchBarStatic) _setupSearchField] + 210
    frame #14: 0x01fc6af6 UIKit`-[UISearchBar initWithCoder:] + 1500
    frame #15: 0x0210bd6d UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
    frame #16: 0x0210bf6e UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1217
    frame #17: 0x0210baa1 UIKit`-[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 114
    frame #18: 0x01d43fa4 UIKit`-[UIView initWithCoder:] + 842
    frame #19: 0x0210bd6d UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
    frame #20: 0x0210baa1 UIKit`-[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 114
    frame #21: 0x01fa67a7 UIKit`-[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 191
    frame #22: 0x0210bd6d UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
    frame #23: 0x0210bf6e UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1217
    frame #24: 0x0210baa1 UIKit`-[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 114
    frame #25: 0x01fa5c21 UIKit`-[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1117
    frame #26: 0x01e0e6f5 UIKit`-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
    frame #27: 0x01e0ee9d UIKit`-[UIViewController loadView] + 302
    frame #28: 0x01e0f0d3 UIKit`-[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
    frame #29: 0x01e0f5d9 UIKit`-[UIViewController view] + 35
    frame #30: 0x01e29942 UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 778
    frame #31: 0x01e368f7 UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 688
    frame #32: 0x01e374e9 UIKit`-[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    frame #33: 0x01f780d1 UIKit`-[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 213
    frame #34: 0x01d5f964 UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    frame #35: 0x0371d82b libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    frame #36: 0x0068345a QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    frame #37: 0x00677244 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 380
    frame #38: 0x006770b0 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 26
    frame #39: 0x005dd7fa QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 294
    frame #40: 0x005deb85 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 393
    frame #41: 0x005df258 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92
    frame #42: 0x0395436e CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    frame #43: 0x039542bf CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    frame #44: 0x03932254 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    frame #45: 0x039319d3 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    frame #46: 0x039317eb CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #47: 0x048dd5ee GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 192
    frame #48: 0x048dd42b GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
    frame #49: 0x01cf0f9b UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1225
  * frame #50: 0x00008f2d `main(argc=1, argv=0xbfffed90) + 141 at main.m:16
```

I have no idea whats happening here. All I did was dragged a UISearchBar in the main view a view controller in the storyboard. every thing works fine without the search bar but when i add the search bar and run the app. I get this crash when i got to the view controller. and the strange thing is that the control does not even go to the `viewDidLoad` of the view controller. Anybody else faced this issue before? What should I do?

## UPDATE

A proper crash trace:

```
2014-08-09 10:07:39.518 MyWorkflowww[20945:607] -[UIView setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcf04830
2014-08-09 10:07:39.522 MyWorkflowww[20945:607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcf04830'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x039891e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x037088e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x03a26243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0397950b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x039790ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   UIKit                               0x01fcdba4 -[UISearchBar(UISearchBarStatic) _updateMagnifyingGlassView] + 486
    6   UIKit                               0x01fcdcdb -[UISearchBar(UISearchBarStatic) _setupSearchField] + 210
    7   UIKit                               0x01fc3af6 -[UISearchBar initWithCoder:] + 1500
    8   UIKit                               0x02108d6d UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
    9   UIKit                               0x02108f6e UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1217
    10  UIKit                               0x02108aa1 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 114
    11  UIKit                               0x01d40fa4 -[UIView initWithCoder:] + 842
    12  UIKit                               0x02108d6d UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
    13  UIKit                               0x02108aa1 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 114
    14  UIKit                               0x01fa37a7 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 191
    15  UIKit                               0x02108d6d UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
    16  UIKit                               0x02108f6e UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1217
    17  UIKit                               0x02108aa1 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 114
    18  UIKit                               0x01fa2c21 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1117
    19  UIKit                               0x01e0b6f5 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
    20  UIKit                               0x01e0be9d -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
    21  UIKit                               0x01e0c0d3 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
    22  UIKit                               0x01e0c5d9 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    23  UIKit                               0x01d2c267 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 66
    24  UIKit                               0x01d2c5ef -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
    25  UIKit                               0x01d2c86b -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    26  UIKit                               0x01d373c8 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
    27  MyWorkflowww                        0x000091c2 -[MyAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 610
    28  UIKit                               0x01ce714f -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 309
    29  UIKit                               0x01ce7aa1 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1810
    30  UIKit                               0x01cec667 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    31  UIKit                               0x01d00f92 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3517
    32  UIKit                               0x01d01555 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    33  UIKit                               0x01cee250 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 683
    34  GraphicsServices                    0x048dbf02 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    35  GraphicsServices                    0x048dba0d PurpleEventCallback + 46
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x03904ca5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x039049db __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x0392f68c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x0392e9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x0392e7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    41  UIKit                               0x01cebd9c -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    42  UIKit                               0x01cedf9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    43                         0x00008f2d main + 141
    44  libdyld.dylib                       0x044f36d9 start + 1
    45  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project (CMD+SHIFT+K) and/or deleting derived data (from the Organizer tab)

Comment: Have you got any old / unused connections in a storyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem, apparently i was using a appearance method that was setting the leftView to a UIView. and when the UITextField inside UISearchBar was setting the magnifier image to UITextField's leftView (which was a UIView) thats why it was crashing. Fixed It.