# UIImagePickerController is getting crash while allocation with "[UIView setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance " message

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am working on a simple tab bar based application. I am trying to open image picker to select some images from gallery with generic code as follows:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum]) {
picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage,nil];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;

picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

But it's crashing with very weird logs.

```
2015-10-18 22:42:54.959  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79eb3c10'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02b1adf6 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x027a4a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02b22a75 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x02a6b9c7 ___forwarding___ + 1047
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x02a6b58e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   UIKit                               0x010c1e9f -[UISearchBar(UISearchBarStatic) _updateMagnifyingGlassView] + 490
    6   UIKit                               0x010c08d9 -[UISearchBar _applySearchBarStyle] + 385
    7   UIKit                               0x010c22e2 -[UISearchBar(UISearchBarStatic) _setupSearchField] + 1065
    8   UIKit                               0x010b7da2 -[UISearchBar searchField] + 48
    9   PhotosUI                            0x11bfd271 +[PUSearchViewController(PresentationHelpers) newSearchBar] + 103
    10  PhotosUI                            0x11b807fb -[PUSearchButtonItem initWithNavigationItem:target:action:] + 477
    11  PhotosUI                            0x11a4476b -[PUPhotosGridViewController searchButtonItem] + 130
    12  PhotosUI                            0x11a48520 -[PUPhotosGridViewController updateNavigationBarAnimated:] + 458
    13  PhotosUI                            0x11a472ed -[PUPhotosGridViewController updatePeripheralInterfaceAnimated:] + 110
    14  PhotosUI                            0x11a4a3b4 -[PUPhotosGridViewController updateInterfaceForModelReloadAnimated:] + 267
    15  PhotosUI                            0x11a3fe46 -[PUPhotosGridViewController viewWillAppear:] + 361
    16  UIKit                               0x00ebd14f -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 545
    17  UIKit                               0x00ebd6ca -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 148
    18  UIKit                               0x014a0e0f -[UICollectionViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 59
    19  UIKit                               0x00eef389 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 931
    20  UIKit                               0x00eeffdb -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 669
    21  UIKit                               0x00ee05ca -[UINavigationController _setViewControllers_7_0:transition:animated:operation:] + 2983
    22  UIKit                               0x00edf70b -[UINavigationController _setViewControllers:transition:animated:operation:] + 476
    23  UIKit                               0x00edf9a2 -[UINavigationController _setViewControllers:transition:animated:] + 65
    24  UIKit                               0x00ede9f3 __54-[UINavigationController setViewControllers:animated:]_block_invoke + 1277
    25  UIKit                               0x00edea82 __54-[UINavigationController setViewControllers:animated:]_block_invoke298 + 33
    26  UIKit                               0x00ec515d +[UIViewController _performWithoutDeferringTransitions:] + 107
    27  UIKit                               0x00ede4d2 -[UINavigationController setViewControllers:animated:] + 549
    28  UIKit                               0x01066c0c -[UIImagePickerController _setupControllersForCurrentSourceType] + 187
    29  UIKit                               0x01066159 -[UIImagePickerController viewWillAppear:] + 62
    30  UIKit                               0x00ebd14f -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 545
    31  UIKit                               0x00ebd6ca -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 148
    32  UIKit                               0x00ed50b1 -[UIViewController(UIContainerViewControllerProtectedMethods) beginAppearanceTransition:animated:] + 200
    33  UIKit                               0x00e91784 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 786
    34  UIKit                               0x00ec521b __40+[UIViewController _scheduleTransition:]_block_invoke + 18
    35  UIKit                               0x00d8b62e ___afterCACommitHandler_block_invoke + 15
    36  UIKit                               0x00d8b5d9 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 415
    37  UIKit                               0x00d8b3ee _afterCACommitHandler + 545
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x02a3dfbe __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x02a3df00 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 400
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x02a3393a __CFRunLoopRun + 1226
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x02a331ab CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x02a32fdb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    43  GraphicsServices                    0x051d624f GSEventRunModal + 192
    44  GraphicsServices                    0x051d608c GSEventRun + 104
    45  UIKit                               0x00d61e16 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    46  CrimeChat                           0x0014311d main + 141
    47  libdyld.dylib                       0x03470ac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I want to add one thing that same code is working in other projects. I have tried in different projects.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214509/uisearchbar-in-a-uiviewcontroller-crashing might be useful.

Comment: @michaelrccurtis  hey I have already checked this, but I am not allocating any component which use setImage methods.

Comment: Well, the problem is that `setImage` is not being found, which means that there is a `UIView` where there should be a `UIImageView` or similar.

Comment: @michaelrccurtis  I have removed this line `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];` . Its still not working. I even tried in  a new test tab with single Button on that viewcontroller and called this code on its click.